# The Button over SupportMapFragment inside a viewpager programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling with something really simple. ( or at least this was my idea.. )

I would need to put a simple button on top of a map inside a viewpager.

Actually I'm creating the supportmapfragment programmatically and adding it to the crated viewpager adapter .

```
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager());

   mapFrag =  new SupportMapFragment();
   mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

   adapter.addFragment(mapFrag, getString(R.string.maptab));
```

now...   to put a button on top I would need the view from supportmapfragment so I can push up "my button_" via addview.

I cannot understand how to retrieve the view without extending the class for supportmapfragment but this would need me to create a custom supportmapfragment class.

any idea?

after suggestion:   I made a test with a relative layout :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/rlMap"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</fragment>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Button 1"/>
```

this make button appear for a second (before map load) then being uncovered by map . even putting button inside the fragment sort same effect

Answer (score 0):

Even if you try and put the button over the fragment's view, you will still need to set a click listener and do some logic when it's pressed. I think that would make the existing code a bit messy, passing a responsibility of the fragment (registering the button click listener) to the activity.

What I would do if I were you would be create a new `Fragment` with some `ConstraintLayout` that contains the underlying map and the button (but does not extend `SupportMapFragment`). It would be a wrapper fragment where you can also handle the button with its events, and whatever would be needed more.